# Redux dispatching only half of the functions

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, reducers

So, I want to directly replace the value of priority which is initially 1 to a different value. I created a redux function for it, but it's sending the function more than once.

Action

```
export const editPriority = (id, listID, newPriority) => {
  return {
    type: TRELLO_CONSTANTS.PRIORITY,
    payload: { id, listID, newPriority },
  };
};
```

```
      const { id, newPriority } = action.payload;
      const card = state[id];
      card.priority = newPriority;
      return { ...state, [`card-${id}`]: card };
    }
```

export const TRELLO_CONSTANTS = {
  PRIORITY: 'PRIORITY',
};

```
and here's my function -

import {editPriority} from './actionTypes.js';

const card=({dispatch})=> {
  const [newPriority, priority] = useState(); 
}

const changePriority = (e) => {
    // newPriority(e);
    priority(e);
    dispatch(editPriority(id, listID, priority));
    console.log(priority);
  };

// and the main function


<button onClick={() => changePriority(1)}>1</button>
<button onClick={() => changePriority(2)}>0</button>

{priority === 0 ? <p>0</p> : null}
{priority === 1 ? <p>1</p> : null}
```

So whenever, I click the button, it only dispatches id and listID, not the priority. Plus I'm also not able to make the last 2 ternary operators work. Is this a wrong way to access them?

This is the output I get in redux extension -

```
{
  type: 'PRIORITY',
  payload: {
    id: 'card-0',
    listID: 'list-0'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `e` directly to `editPriority`, since `state` updates are asynchronous  in nature, and the change caused by `priority(e)` won't be reflected immediately.

```
const changePriority = (e) => {
    // newPriority(e);
    priority(e);
    dispatch(editPriority(id, listID, e));
 };
```

Suggestion:

In reducer, do not mutate the original state directly

```
const { id, newPriority } = action.payload;
const card = {...state[id]};
card.priority = newPriority;
return { ...state, [`card-${id}`]: card };
```

Also your priority state name is `newPriority`

So, use that value in render:

```
{newPriority === 0 ? <p>0</p> : null}
{newPriority === 1 ? <p>1</p> : null}
```

**Suggestion**: While naming your states you can use it as `const [priority, setPriority] = useState();` to avoid the confustion

Comment: Can you also tell me the way how to make them work?``` {priority === 0 ? <p>0</p> : null}
                {priority === 1 ? <p>1</p> : null}```

Comment: Updated my answer. Please read the react-hooks `useState` documentation to understand better.

Comment: but when I go to a different page and come back this 1 thingy isn't visible anymore. is the state getting reset?

Comment: In such a case, you must not maintain the priority state locally but receive it from the redux store and render using that value

Comment: oh yes. Thanks a lot for the help. You solved almost everything.